# Register global handler for URI prefix

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to somehow associate certain protocols with mine app so when user tries to open link starting with "myapp://" it will launch my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This capability does not exist for 3rd party apps on the v1 platform. You wouldn't be the first to want it though. Commenting on Microsoft's suggestion forum would not hurt.